# Select duplicate rows based on time difference and occurrence count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, duplicates

I have a table like this :

[image: my table]

As you can see, some records with the same **farsi_pelak** field have been added(detected) **more than 1 time** within a few seconds.

That's happened because of some application bug which has been fixed.

Now I need to select and then delete duplicate rows which have been added at the same time (+- few seconds)

And this is my query :

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
    y.id, y.farsi_pelak , y.detection_date_p , y.detection_time
      FROM dbo._tbl_detection y
          INNER JOIN       
        (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
                        farsi_pelak , detection_date_p
                        FROM dbo._tbl_detection WHERE camera_id = 2
                        GROUP BY farsi_pelak , detection_date_p
                        HAVING COUNT(farsi_pelak)>1) dt 
                        ON 
                        y.farsi_pelak=dt.farsi_pelak AND y.detection_date_p =dt.detection_date_p
                        ORDER BY farsi_pelak , detection_date_p DESC
```

But I can't calculate the time difference because my **detection_time** field should not be grouped by.

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use `LAG` function to get the values from the "previous" row.

Then calculate the difference between adjacent timestamps and find those rows where this difference is small.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,farsi_pelak
        ,detection_date_p
        ,detection_time
        ,LAG(detection_time) OVER (PARTITION BY farsi_pelak 
            ORDER BY detection_date_p, detection_time) AS prev_detection_time
    FROM dbo._tbl_detection
)
,CTE_Diff
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,farsi_pelak
        ,detection_date_p
        ,detection_time
        ,prev_detection_time
        ,DATEDIFF(second, prev_detection_time, detection_time) AS diff
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    id
    ,farsi_pelak
    ,detection_date_p
    ,detection_time
    ,prev_detection_time
    ,diff
FROM CTE_Diff
WHERE
    diff <= 10
;
```

When you run this query and verify that it returns only rows that you want to delete, you can change the last `SELECT` to `DELETE`:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,farsi_pelak
        ,detection_date_p
        ,detection_time
        ,LAG(detection_time) OVER (PARTITION BY farsi_pelak 
            ORDER BY detection_date_p, detection_time) AS prev_detection_time
    FROM dbo._tbl_detection
)
,CTE_Diff
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,farsi_pelak
        ,detection_date_p
        ,detection_time
        ,prev_detection_time
        ,DATEDIFF(second, prev_detection_time, detection_time) AS diff
    FROM CTE
)
DELETE
FROM CTE_Diff
WHERE
    diff <= 10
;
```

Comment: Thank You , after spending 3 days it works like a charm , you are a SQL hero

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need rownumber to check time as below keeping the earliest time data and discarding the rest detection time for rownums greater than 1

```
     Select   y.id, y.farsi_pelak , 
     y.detection_date_p , y.detection_time, 
     row_number() over (partition by  
       y.farsi_pelak, 
     y.detection_date_p order by 
      y.detection_time) rn
       from ( the above query)  where rn>1
```

Comment: If you partition by unique `id`, all row numbers will be always 1.

Comment: My bad i din see id in the OPs query just now saw they are different will update. Thanks!